# Error during typesetting but exit code is zero

Tags: errors

When I run `xelatex -halt-on-error --recorder issues.tex`, I get

```
[8]
<use  "resources/app_111228-3.png" >
[9] [10] [11] [12] [13]
Runaway argument?
{resources/\caption [xyz\ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \Gin@ii was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.756 

Output written on issues.pdf (13 pages
).
Transcript written on issues.log.
```

which tells me that I have a syntax error in my TeX source. BUT when I try to catch this error with a script or `echo $?`, I see that (Xe)(La)TeX is returning an **exit code of `0` instead of `1` although clearly there was an error during processing**. How am I supposed to detect such situations? Is there a parser to determine the error status of a TeX log? any command line switches?

Comment: I'm getting the exact same issue, and it's a bitch trying to find instances of other people dealing with it. Your options appear to be exit with a 0, or hang for input; both of which are garbage when dealing with an automated script.